# Error de rutas a la hora de exportar proyecto a JAR

Tags: java

Tengo un proyecto en java que tiene un fichero a la altura de src/main/resources. Cuando ejecuto el programa en local funciona y recoge bien el fichero de la ruta.

Pero a la hora de paquetarlo en un jar y desplegar ese proyecto web-server en un máquina externa y hacer llamadas get a una url que usara ese fichero. No me encuentra el fichero y me salta excepción. Para asegurarme de si la ruta estaba bien. 
Use el programa Java Decompiler y le pase el jar para ver su estructura. Y me lleve la sorpresa de que ya no pendía de resouces sino que se encontraba en la raíz. Pero cuando volví a desplegar ese jar con la ruta del fichero cambiada en properties (apuntando a raiz) seguía sin poder localizar el archivo.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Qué ruta estás usando para obtener el fichero?

Comment: Le ruta definida es la siguiente: src/main/resources/file.jks . Y se encuentra en especificada en el fochero properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante saber cómo organiza Maven los proyectos y cómo los empaqueta:

Los proyectos de Maven, a menos que uses unas rutas definidas por ti, siempre tienen un directorio `/src` (de sources)

Dentro suele haber dos subdirectorios, `/src/main` y `/src/test`. El primero tendrá todo el código y los recursos (resources) necesarios para que el programa funcione. El segundo tendrá las test unitarios. Para el propósito que nos ocupa este segundo directorio no es relevante, así que lo ignoraré.

Ya estamos dentro de `/src/main`. Aquí suele haber dos subdirectorios: `./java`, que debería contener **solamente** ficheros `.java` y `./resources`, donde debería estar todo lo demás (ficheros XML, ficheros `.properties`, ficheros de configuración de Spring (properties o yalm), plantillas (por ejemplo ficheros FreeMarker... etc. Si tienes una aplicación web, es posible encontrar una tercera carpeta, `./webapp`, donde estarán los JSP, los ficheros Javascript, CSS y HTML, imágenes...

Ahora lo importante:

- la carpeta `/src/main/java` es compilada, con lo que en el JAR/WAR deberías tener esa misma estructura de directorios y ficheros pero con extensión `.class`. Si te fijas, los paquetes (package) definidos en tus clases definen la estructura de directorio, pero la parte de `/src/main/java` se ignora, se toma esta carpeta como equivalente a la raíz.
- Una vez compilado el proyecto, los recursos se copian **al mismo destino** que los ficheros `.class`, tomando como raíz `/src/main/resources`.

Esto significa que se mezclarán los ficheros compilados con los ficheros de configuración, por lo que si tienes un fichero en `/src/main/resources/file.jks`, pasará a estar en la raíz del JAR/WAR, así que para acceder a él deberías usar una URL como `classpath:/file.jks`. El prefijo `classpath:` indica que el fichero no está en el sistema de ficheros, sino dentro del JAR/WAR

Comment: Gracias por la completa respuesta @Pablo entonces debo seleccionar la carpeta desde el menu de opciones de proyecto -> Java build path del IDE (en este caso eclipse)?

Comment: Entiendo que el termino classpath: pertenece a spring?

Comment: No, realmente pertenece a Java. De hecho [Spring te permite "obviar" esa parte](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access). Respecto a Eclipse, creo que no es necesario tocar nada, simplemente asume que la carpeta resources acabará en la "raíz" de JAR/WAR y usa rutas absolutas desde ahí

Answer (score 0):

Me he encontrado ese problema empaquetando proyectos usando Spring. En ese caso la solución era usar un Bean que es ResourceLoader con el cual si puedes acceder a esos archivos, aún en el empaquetado jar.

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi Solucion en Spring Boot en el caso de una Imagen para un reporte PDF con iText 5.3:

```
Resource resourceImagen = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/images/boletin-header1.png");
InputStream streamImage = resourceImagen.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(streamImage);
Image image = Image.getInstance(bytes);
```

Me funciona perfectamente ya que segun literatura los JAR no puedes acceder al PATH y ahi el motivo de el error en tu codigo.